# How to show oldest metrics from queue? Grafana/Prometheus

Tags: alert, metrics, grafana, prometheus

I have a panel in grafana, which shows current alerts (simple query ALERTS{alertstate="firing"} with instant=enable option). I want to know the time, when alert triggered in first time. How can I do this?

As I think, I need to sort queue for Time values and take the oldest. But I can't find tools for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like this query:

```
timestamp(
    absent(ALERTS{env=~"$env",job=~"$job",alertstate="firing"} offset 1m)
  unless
    absent(ALERTS{env=~"$env",job=~"$job",alertstate="firing"})
)
```

with `Min step = 1m` and `Resolution = 1/1`, but this will give you all the times any alert started to fire (regardless of whether it is still firing or not; and including every time it flipped on).

Or you could use a [Discrete panel](https://grafana.com/plugins/natel-discrete-panel) (which is what I'm doing) to eyeball when alerts started and stopped firing, and optionally when the alert went from warning to critical (if you set them up that way).